# How can I list the WM manager sessions available from the command line?

Tags: command-line, lightdm

How can I list the WM manager sessions available from the command line?
I want to know what sessions are available to pass to thr lightdm-set-defaults utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each session there's a `*.desktop` file in `/usr/share/xsessions/`. The session names  used by lightdm are the file names without the `.desktop`.

You can list them using something like

```
ls /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop | sed -re's:.*/([^.]+)\..*:\1:'
```

To get the names as displayed by the GUI use

```
awk -F= '/^Name=/ {print $2}'  /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop
```